# Fetch recent email from gmail imap using curl

Tags: curl, libcurl, gmail-imap

I can fetch email from gmail imap using curl by passing uid no following query request

> curl imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX;UID=1

But I want to fetch recent 1000 emails from gmail how can i do that what query i need to pass?

I tried imap extension commands from gmail but not success https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions

what query i need change in following query to fecth recent 1000 emails from gmail imap?

> curl imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX;UID=1

Comment: Have you tried extracting the number of emails wanted after making the request? What exactly is not working from the commands you have tried? @Kamlesh

Comment: Yes I can extract number of emails by passing different numbers of UID  in request but like 1 no UID fetch oldest mail from gmail but i have more than 20 thousand email in my gmail so i want to fetch latest 1000 emails
I also tried this follwing query to fetch all email but it's not wokring can you help me what is wrong in this query?

curl "imaps://username:password@imap.gmail.com:/[Gmail]/All Mail"
response : curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct command in order to fetch a specific number mails with IMAP. IMAM works in such a way that you can get a specific email and/or emails from a subcategory, such as all the emails labeled as `INBOX`.

The `UID` is used to uniquely identify an email - so in this situation, you can get the `UID` of the last email and work your way from there.

Comment: I think this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73278439